# Filter by column value and write to file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a table like this:

```
BB1520_v1.0_0103        exon    3329    3601
BB1520_v1.0_0103        exon    3650    4040
BB1520_v1.0_0089        exon    1       862
BB1520_v1.0_0089        exon    1312    1357
BB1520_v1.0_0089        exon    1423    1531
BB1520_v1.0_0084        exon    5196    5283
```

I want to extract the lines by the values in column 1, and save them to 3 different files.

I tried with the following code but didn't work:

```
 awk -F, '{print >$1".txt"}' file.txt
```

Comment: Please include sample output: it isn't clear what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: You're using `,` as the field separator but I can't see a single comma in your sample file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right approach, but you need to fieldsplit on whitespace, not commas (`-F,`). I'm interpreting your question as "the lines should be saved to files with names equalling that in column 1".

```
$ cat file.txt 
BB1520_v1.0_0103        exon    3329    3601
BB1520_v1.0_0103        exon    3650    4040
BB1520_v1.0_0089        exon    1       862
BB1520_v1.0_0089        exon    1312    1357
BB1520_v1.0_0089        exon    1423    1531
BB1520_v1.0_0084        exon    5196    5283
$ awk '{ print >$1".txt"}' file.txt
$ cat BB1520_v1.0_0103.txt 
BB1520_v1.0_0103        exon    3329    3601
BB1520_v1.0_0103        exon    3650    4040
```